# Update value mongo using Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-update, database

I am using Java Mongo driver for the DB interaction. I have regular updates to be performed on the DB rows and the object that is quite nested. Something like this :

MyObject:

```
{
    _id: dbGeneratedId,
    myId: "A String ID that i created",
    myTime: "new Date()",
    myList: 
        [
        {
            myString: "abcdefghij",
            myInteger: 9000
        },
        {
            myString: "qwertyasdf",
            myInteger: 9001
        },
        {
            myString: "loremipsum",
            myInteger: 9002
        }
    ]
}
```

Each update involves either adding a new List item under `myList` or appending some string to the `myString` object in each of the List item. I found a lot of references for writing/finding items and none for updating items in a nested object. Can someone help me with this.

Edit 1: It would also be helpful if someone points out how to get one of the List items based on a `myInteger` search

PS: new to mongo thro Java, excuse my ignorance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert new list item using the [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/) operator.

You can run the following command on the shell to add new list item.

```
db.myObject.update({"myId" : "A String ID that i created"},{$push:{myList: {myString:"new string", myInteger:9003}}})
```

You can add list item using Java Driver as follows.

```
        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("myObject");
        DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("myId", "A String ID that i created");

        DBObject listItem = new BasicDBObject();
        listItem.put("myString", "my new string");
        listItem.put("myInteger", 9003);

        DBObject updateObj = new BasicDBObject("myList", listItem);

        coll.update(query, new BasicDBObject("$push", updateObj));
```

You can get single element as follows on the shell.

```
db.myObject.find({"myList.myInteger" : 9003}, {"myList.$" : 1})
```

From Java Driver you can run same code as follows :

```
DBCursor cur = coll.find(new BasicDBObject("myList.myInteger", 9003), new BasicDBObject("myList.$", 1));
```

You can remove object as follows :

```
db.nested.update({"myId" : "A String ID that i created"},{$pull:{myList: {myString:"new string", myInteger:9003}}})
```

In Java you can do it as follows :

```
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("myObject");
    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("myId", "A String ID that i created");

    DBObject listItem = new BasicDBObject();
    listItem.put("myString", "my new string");
    listItem.put("myInteger", 9003);

    DBObject updateObj = new BasicDBObject("myList", listItem);

    coll.update(query, new BasicDBObject("$pull", updateObj));
```

PS : Currently it is not possible to update all items in an array. There is an open issue on the Jira. You can check it from [JIRA-1243](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243)

Comment: This did help!. Also, do you know how to update/append a value already in the list?. Say, i need to update the `myString` value of `loremipsum` to `loremipsumfoobar`, how do i do that? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I have updated my answer. Currently it is not possible to update all array items. There is an open issue on Jira.

Comment: On a side note, could you share a snippet showing how to delete one of the objects from `myList`.

Comment: Updated my answer. Check it again.